# fTools "Join Attributes by Location" missing in SEXTANTE/Processing Toolbox

Tags: qgis, sextante, ftools, qgis-processing

I am working with the new Processing Framework in QGIS 2.0.1.
I really like the graphical modeler, because it allows my to make my own tools without having to be able to write pyhton or any other programming language.
But it seems like some of the fTools (the Vector-Tools in QGIS) are missing?
For example "Join Attributes by Location". 
Is this an error, or is there a reason for that tool being missing in SEXTANTE?
To make things a bit more clear, I attached 2 Screenshots to show which tool I mean.
Here you see all the tools avaliable in the Processing Framework
[image: Here is the list of vector tools in the framework]

Here you see the tool I am looking for..
[image: Here is the tool in the vector toolbar in QGIS]

So is there any way to get the Tool in the Framework?
If not, has anyone an idea how to get a similar result with another tool?

(Futher information on the task i want to accomplish:
I've got a .shp with landlot, and a .shp with 3 polygons, and I want to have a field in the attribute table of the landlots which shows which of the polygons is covering which landlot.)

Thanks in adavance!

Gunnar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool has been added and is available in the QGIS 2.4 version of Sextante under the name **Join by location**.